# select query with Not IN keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, notin

I have **two Tables** as below..

1. tbPatientEncounter
2. tbVoucher

when i execute `select query` as below

```
Select EncounterIDP,EncounterNumber from tbPatientEncounter
```

[image]

it returens me 180 rows. and

Select VoucherIDP,EncounterIDF from tbVoucher

[image]

above query returns me 165 rows.

but i want to execute select query that returns me data like EncounterIDP not in tbVoucher, for that i have tried below Select query...

```
    Select * from tbPatientEncounter pe 
    where pe.EncounterIDP not in 
    (Select v.EncounterIDF from tbVoucher v )
```

it doesn't returns any row. in first image it shows `EncounterIDP 9 in tbPatientEncounter`, but it not inserted in tbVoucher for that i have tried select Query like

```
Select * from tbVoucher where EncounterIDF = 9
```

it returns me 0 rows.

My question is `what is wrong with my above Not In Query.?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all likelihood, the problem is `NULL` values in `tbVoucher`.  Try this:

```
Select *
from tbPatientEncounter pe 
where pe.EncounterIDP not in (Select v.EncounterIDF
                              from tbVoucher v
                              where v.EncounterIDF is not NULL
                             )
```

Comment: `@Gordon Linoff` thanks for your answer, but how could you know there is null value at `EncounterIDF` colomn.?

Answer (score 2):

Are you comparing the correct fields in tbVoucher?

Try using a left join

```
Select EncounterIDP,EncounterNumber from tbPatientEncounter
       left join tbVoucher on EncounterIDP = EncounterIDF
where EncounterIDF is null
```

Comment: `@podiluska` i want it with `not in` query. what is wrong with my query.

Answer (score 0):

Call me a skeptic because I don't see anything wrong with your query. Is this really all in the query or did you simplify it for us?

```
Select * from tbPatientEncounter pe 
where pe.EncounterIDP not in 
(Select v.EncounterIDF from tbVoucher v )
```